# ‘Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. …’ Warning, but TabBar Controller *is* root view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I'm getting a warning in Xcode as soon as I launch my app: `Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation.`

This is what my storyboard looks like:

```
                        +------ Nav Controller ------ View Controller
                        |
                        |
                        |
Tab Bar View Controller +------ Nav Controller ------ View Controller
                        |
                        |
                        |
                        +------ Nav Controller ------ View Controller
```

All are custom sub-classes.

I found similar questions on SO, but all of them were happening because the TabBarViewController wasn't root (or, Initial View Controller), which in my case **it is**.

I've tried setting `tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;` as well as

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

I'm stumped! No weird behaviour, nothing's broken, but I can't get rid of that pesky warning.

By the way, the app isn't finished and the reason the View Controllers are embedded in Nav Controllers is because they will segue to other View Controllers eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a bug, according to an answer I got on Apple’s Developer Forums.

Answer (score 1):

If you are compiling for iOS 7 `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is **deprecated**. You should be using `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` instead.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't address the issue of the warning appearing out of nowhere, without my using any rotation-related customization anywhere in the app. I only put in the `shouldAutorotatetoInterfaceOrientation` because it was suggested in a different question here on SO, then I took it out when it didn't fix my issue.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I tried implementing `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in the root view and the subsequent views to double the declarations already made in Xcode's GUI and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Also, I found a similar question on SO where somebody was getting that warning from setting some tabBarItems programmatically (I’m setting the icons and colours programmatically). Commenting out that code didn't remove the warning either.